# Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift3, xcode8, ios10

When I submit **.ipa** I get this error.

**Invalid Swift Support - The SwiftSupport folder is missing. Rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode and resubmit it.**

[image]

This project has **Swift** and **Objective-C** classes. And set `Always Embed Swift Standards Libraries` = `YES` in **Xcode 8.2.1**

Any Idea. Already done everything.

Thanks.

Comment: Any idea......?

Comment: I am currently struggling with the same bug, have you maybe found a solution?

Comment: @JosuéH. Did you get the solution for this? Please let me know if you found any.

Comment: Solution:

I've tried to archive with configuration where EMBEDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT  set to NO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I've tried to archive with configuration where EMBEDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT set to NO.

Comment: I have same issued and I changed flag from YES to NO , but still sending same issue.